# YAML in Ruby. What is the difference between load and load_file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have this practice.yml file:

```
foo: whatever 
bar: 
 - 
   fruit: apple 
   name: steve 
   sport: baseball 
 - more 
 - 
   python: rocks 
   perl: papers 
   ruby: scissorses
```

What is the difference under the hood between #load and #load_file?

#load seems to do this magic and takes a string:

```
pry(main)> YAML.load("'a'")
"a"
[11] pry(main)> YAML.load("a:1")
"a:1"
[12] pry(main)> YAML.load("-a")
"-a"
[13] pry(main)> YAML.load("[a]")
[
    [0] "a"
]
[14] pry(main)> YAML.load("[a,bc]")
[
    [0] "a",
    [1] "bc"
]
```

Whereas load_file seems to just take a file with valid yaml inside:

```
irb(main):002:0> YAML.load_file("practice.yml")
=> {"foo"=>"whatever", "bar"=>[{"fruit"=>"apple", "name"=>"steve", "sport"=>"baseball"}, "more", {"python"=>"rocks", "perl"=>"papers", "ruby"=>"scissorses"}]}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

load_file calls load, like this:

```
    def self.load_file(filename, options={})
      if SafeYAML::MULTI_ARGUMENT_YAML_LOAD
        File.open(filename, 'r:bom|utf-8') { |f| self.load(f, filename, options) }

      else
        # Ruby pukes on 1.9.2 if we try to open an empty file w/ 'r:bom|utf-8';
        # so we'll not specify those flags here. This mirrors the behavior for
        # unsafe_load_file so it's probably preferable anyway.
        self.load File.open(filename), nil, options
      end
    end
```

Now the prototype for load() is

```
def self.load(yaml, filename=nil, options={})
```

so basically load_file is opening up the file name and passing the resulting string to load(), after checking for some empty file case related to Ruby 1.9.2

Comment: In that case, what magic is going on in #load since it seems to handle strings and output hashes or arrays depending on string markup

Comment: Like this: (sorry for formatting) $ bundle show yaml
~/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/safe_yaml-1.0.4
$ mate `!!`
mate `bundle show yaml`

Comment: where mate is textmate, subl works just as well, then just search the project for 'load_file'

Comment: well it calls  Psych.parse(yaml) and so that magic is over in the Psych gem

Comment: which is not a gem, but is native code over here http://github.com/tenderlove/psych

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding. So the input is always a string, which can contain markup for strings, arrays,  etc. That just the YAML spec ...http://yaml.org/